# Break out of switch statement execute one case

Tags: switch-statement, break, execution

So basically, I am trying to get the switch statement to only execute one time. And not execute all of them.
Assume the player has all of the keys in their inventory.
I want only one case to execute and not go through all the cases.
(I'd like to only see one execute)

```
public int[] allKeys = {1543, 1544, 1545, 1546, 1547, 1548};

if (player.getInventory().containsAny(allKeys)) {
                      for (int id : allKeys) {
                          switch(id) {
                          case 1543:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                          case 1544:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                          case 1545:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                          case 1546:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                          case 1547:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                          case 1548:
                              System.out.println("executed");
                              break;
                            default:
                              System.out.println("error!");
                          }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: just remove the for loop, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `switch` does only do "one at a time" - it is the fact your switch is in a for loop that is causing you problems...

You could put a "break" after the switch `switch(x) { ... } break;`, but really why loop when you don't want to - just switch on say the first key.

Comment: But then I am losing the id variable.

Comment: Something like `int id = keys.first()` will get you an id variable. To be honest what you are doing seems odd. Are you just trying to check if a player has one of a predefined set of keys? Just working on one from a set seems wrong (without knowing what you are trying to do...)

Comment: depending on which key the player has, the action will be different. They can have all the keys, but I only want it to use one key at a time.

Comment: Sounds more like you want `if player.keys.contains(Most_Important_Key) { } else if player.keys.contains(Second_Most_Important_Key) {}` or something like that.  The need (or lack thereof) a loop through all of the keys is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks!! John that was something I was going for!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently running the switch case inside the for loop that goes through every id's inside the array allKeys. Because you assumed the user to have allKeys, I would just remove the for loop, and pick whatever key you want the user to execute, and let that key go through the switch statement.